# How to stop CSS Keyframes Animation flicker on repeat

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following code that uses three transparent images and moves them through the screen to simulate snow/star fall.

My issue is after the animation goes for the specified time (in this case 5 seconds) it flickers when the animation starts again.

How can I fix this to not flicker, so it is one continuous animation?
See an example here:  https://repl.it/@shane8johnson/InbornGruesomeDatamart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    .container{width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;}
                .container{
                      background-color: black;
                      background-image: url('stars1.png'), url('stars2.png'), url('stars3.png');  
                      animation: snow 5s linear infinite;
                          }     
                 @keyframes snow {
                            0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
                            100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px}
                                 }
  </style>
 </head>
   <body>
     <div class="container"> </div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is the result of your animation's movement vectors being a non-integer multiple of the actual images. As a result, by the time the animation ends (or loops around) stars1.png (for example) has been moved 500px to the right, and 1000px down - but the actual image dimensions are 1100px x 600px. So when the animation reaches the end it has moved a little less than half it's width, and one and two thirds times its height. At which point it jumps back to 0px, 0px.

The simplest way to fix this is to make sure your movement vectors are some integer multiple of the individual image dimensions. For example, try changing this:

```
100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px}
```

to this:

```
100% {background-position: 1100px 600px, -640px 512px, 2287px 1544px}
```

You may also want to change your animation time to something more like 10 seconds.

All I did there was make sure your images each move exactly one whole multiple of their width and height before the animation loops. That way they're exactly where they were when the animation started - and no flicker.

Comment: Brillant! That did seem to solve the issue! In my production environment I have it set to 20 seconds, but for the example I set it to 5sec so you would not have to wait 20 full seconds to see the flicker. I appreciate the help!